# List box detecta que iteam está a ser selecionado

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu quero que quando eu der double click no item da listbox, when start ele faça uma ação, quando eu der double click noutro item qualquer ele faça outra ação.

Código:

```
//btnWhenClicked
private void btnWhenStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItemsBox.Items.Add("When Start"); //é este iteam que eu quero que detect
    btnWhenStart.Hide();
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "MyTest.txt";

    //Create And Write File
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("using System;");
            sw.WriteLine("using System.Collections.Generic;");
            sw.WriteLine("using System.Linq;");
            sw.WriteLine("using System.Text;");
            sw.WriteLine("using System.Threading.Tasks;");

            sw.WriteLine("\r\n namespace CMD");
            sw.WriteLine("{");
            sw.WriteLine("    class Program");
            sw.WriteLine("    {");
            sw.WriteLine("        static void Main(string[] args)");
            sw.WriteLine("        {");
            sw.Close();
        }

    }



}

//delete ListItemsBox Selected Item
private void ListItemsBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "MyTest.txt";
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        ListItemsBox.Items.Remove(ListItemsBox.SelectedItem);
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui descobrir como se faz é mais simples do que parece

```
private void ListItemsBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "MyTest.cs";
    if (ListItemsBox.SelectedItem.Equals("When Start"))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?All items will be deleted including all files!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ListItemsBox.Items.Clear();
            File.Delete(path);
            btnWhenStart.Show();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ListItemsBox.Items.Remove(ListItemsBox.SelectedItem);
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
    }

}
```